# How to use hover so that the h1 can grow in size but not cover my bottom text or move the page

Tags: html, css, hover

Right now the #title:hover text that says "Pulse" is increasing in size but also moves down the page. For example the pulse picture and scroll wheel moves down when the hover makes my text grow bigger. I can't seem to increase the size of the pulse text while not covering the bottom "the man with the heart" text and also not moving the page at the same time.

What I am basically trying to say is how can I change the hover text to expand in size but not move the whole page and all its elements slightly down.

Please Help! Thank You!

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script> src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>


<main id="main">
  <h1 class="title">Pulse</h1>
  <p> The Man with the Heart </p>
    <img id="pulse"
          src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/rainbowsix/images/3/36/Large-pulse.30ab3682.png/revision/latest?cb=20171224002812" alt= "Sexy Bald Man" >


</main>
```

styles:

```
html
{
  font-family: Cursive;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 20px 50px 20px;
  background-color: #FFC44F;
  margin-bottom: 0x;
}


.title:hover {
  color:red;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 100px;
}

p{
  margin-top: -70px;
  text-align: center;
}

img{
  display:block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#pulse {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: -100px -20px 0px -20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hover actually works, but because you are changing the height on hover so the object gets bigger and if you move a small back it's now off the object when it's not on hover so it stops, 
For that to fix try to separate the H1 from the background as I made in the example I added a div with the class heder and placed your H1 style like this it should only depend on the H1 word.

Take a look...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <style>

    html{  font-family: Cursive;}

    .heder {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 20px 20px 50px 20px;
      background-color: #FFC44F;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }


    .title:hover {
      color:red;
      padding: 20px 20px 50px 20px;
      margin: 0px;
      transform: scale(1.1);
    }

    p{
      margin-top:-30px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    img{
      height: auto;
      max-width: 100%;
    }

    #pulse {
      padding: 10px;
      margin: -100px -20px 0px -20px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <main id="main">
        <div class="heder">
      <h1 class="title">Pulse</h1>
      <p> The Man with the Heart </p>
    </div>
        <img id="pulse"
              src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/rainbowsix/images/3/36/Large-pulse.30ab3682.png/revision/latest?cb=20171224002812" alt= "Sexy Bald Man" >


    </main>
```

Answer (score 0):

The transformed text in `<h1>` overwrite the text in `<p>`

Here is a workaround:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script> src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>
<style>

html
{
  font-family: Cursive;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 20px 50px 20px;
  background-color: #FFC44F;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}


h1:hover {
  color:red;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

p{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FFC44F;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

img{
  display:block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#pulse {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: -100px -20px 0px -20px;
}
</style>

<main id="main">
  <div  class="title">
    <h1>Pulse</h1>
  </div>
  <p> The Man with the Heart </p>
    <img id="pulse"
          src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/rainbowsix/images/3/36/Large-pulse.30ab3682.png/revision/latest?cb=20171224002812" alt= "Sexy Bald Man" >


</main>
```